# Ajax and Json post method - php parser and Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, datatables

I've got a small problem regarding ajax and json.

I'm using datatables in my project, which has a .toArray(); to get a selected row into an array. Afterwards I make a ajax post to convert it from Javascript to PHP.

**JS**

```
var rowArray = dt.rows({
    selected: true
}).data().toArray();
rowArray = JSON.stringify(rowArray);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'customer.php',
    data: {
        rowArray
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['rowArray']);
$phparra = array();
foreach ($json as $value) {
    $phparra[] = $value;
}
```

I use the data afterwards to pass it into a PHP function.

I do not know where the exact problem is, but I think it's the format of the array or the decode part.

If I replace the `rowArray` with a simple array like this:

**JS**

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "asdasd", "123123"];
cars = JSON.stringify(cars);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'customer.php',
    data: {
        cars
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['cars']);
$phparra = array();
foreach ($json as $value) {
    $phparra[] = $value;
}
```

It works perfectly and passes the data to the PHP function and so on.

Any idea how to change the parser or something? 
Here's the form data

rowArray:

```
rowArray: [{
    "DT_RowId": "row_100030",
    "crapper_customer_intranet": {
        "kundenr": "100030",
        "navn": "c/o Plejehjemmet Sandfeldgården",
        "cvrnr": null
    },
    "nessus_vulnerability": {
        "ip": null
    }
}]
```

cars:

```
cars: ["Saab","Volvo","BMW","asdasd","123123"]
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: change `$json = json_decode($_POST['rowArray']);` to  `$json = json_decode($_POST['rowArray'], true);` to get an associative array back which you can cycle through with a foreach.